# Saving multiple activities to database in a loop in Brightway

Tags: brightway

I have a loop that generates data and writes it to a database:

```
myDatabase = Database('myDatabase')
for i in range(10):
    #some code here that generates dictionaries that can be saved as activities
     myDatabase.write({('myDatabase', 'valid code'): activityDict})
```

Single activities thus created can be saved to the database. However, when creating more than one, the length of the database is always 1 and only the last activity makes its way to the database.

Because I have lots of very big datasets, it is not convenient to store all of them in a single dictionary and write to the database all at once.

Is there a way to incrementally add activities to an existing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Normal activity writing

`Database.write()` will replace the entire database. The best approach is to create the database in python, and then write the entire thing:

```
data = {}
for i in range(10):
    # some code here that generates data
    data['foo'] = 'bar'
Database('myDatabase').write(data)
```

### Dynamically generating datasets

However, if you are dynamically creating aggregated datasets from an existing database, you can create the individual datasets in a custom generator. This generator will need to support the following:

- `__iter__`: Returns the database keys. Used to check that each dataset belongs to the database being written. Therefor we only need to return the first element.
- `__len__`: Number of datasets to write.
- `keys`: Used to add keys to `mapping`.
- `values`: Used to add activity locations to `geomapping`. As the locations will be the same in our source database and aggregated system database, we can just give the original datasets here.
- `items`: The new keys and datasets.

Here is the code:

```
class IterativeSystemGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, from_db_name, to_db_name):
        self.source = Database(from_db_name)
        self.new_name = to_db_name
        self.lca = LCA({self.source.random(): 1})
        self.lca.lci(factorize=True)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.source)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield ((self.new_name,))

    def get_exchanges(self):
        vector = self.lca.inventory.sum(axis=1)
        assert vector.shape == (len(self.lca.biosphere_dict), 1)
        return [{
                    'input': flow,
                    'amount': float(vector[index]),
                    'type': 'biosphere',
                } for flow, index in self.lca.biosphere_dict.items()
                if abs(float(vector[index])) > 1e-17]

    def keys(self):
        for act in self.source:
            yield (self.new_name, act['code'])

    def values(self):
        for act in self.source:
            yield act

    def items(self):
        for act in self.source:
            self.lca.redo_lci({act: 1})
            obj = copy.deepcopy(act._data)
            obj['database'] = self.new_name
            obj['exchanges'] = self.get_exchanges()
            yield ((self.new_name, obj['code']), obj)
```

And usage:

```
new_name = "ecoinvent 3.2 cutoff aggregated"
new_data = IterativeSystemGenerator("ecoinvent 3.2 cutoff", new_name)
Database(new_name).write(new_data)
```

#### Limitations of this approach

If you are writing so many datasets or exchanges within datasets that you are running into memory problems, then you are also probably using the wrong tool. The current system of database tables and matrix builders uses sparse matrices. In this case, dense matrices would make much more sense. For example, the [IO table backend](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/default/bw2data/backends/iotable/__init__.py) skips the database entirely, and just writes [processed arrays](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/lca.html#turning-processed-data-arrays-in-matrices). It will take a long time to load and create the biosphere matrix if it has 13.000 * 1.500 = 20.000.000 entries. In this specific case, my first instinct is to try one of the following:

- Don't write the biosphere flows into the database, but save them separately per aggregated process, and then add them after the inventory calculation.
- Create a separate database for each aggregated system process.

Comment: I failed to mention in my original question that I couldn't put everything in one dictionary because of the shear amount of data: I have approximately 13000 datasets with 2000 elementary flows each (aggregated versions of the ecoinvent database, which I aggregate myself because of memory issues when loading the scoSpold version). I have edited the question.

Comment: My former comment pertains to the pre-edit version of the answer. This version answers it perfectly, and I have used this code to generate "LCI" versions of my favourite databases. However, because of the limitations noted above, I don't use them. I have instead created a database with just scores for selected methods saved in the B matrix.